# Insertar 2 elemenetos arbol ordenado C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, modular

Estoy intentando insertar 2 elementos (numero de teléfono y nombre), y que al introducir el numero de teléfono me encuentre el nombre asociado a dicho numero de teléfono. Lo que tengo actualmente inserta solamente el número de telefono y no se como hacer para añadir el nombre y que estén asociados. (el código conforme lo que tengo funciona) [URL código completo](https://pastebin.com/RK9MT1Pe)

**Código main:**

```
... switch (opcion)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\nTelefono a insertar: ");
        scanf("%d",&aux);
        a = insertar(a, aux);
        printf("\nTelefono insertado");
       /* printf("\nNombre a insertar: ");
        scanf("%d",&aux2);
        a = insertar(a, aux2);
        printf("\nNombre insertado");
        */break;

    case 2:
        printf("\nNumero a encontrar: ");
        scanf("%d",&aux);
        if(encontrar(a, aux) != NULL)
        {
            printf("\nNumero de telefono: %d", encontrar(a, aux)->valor);
            //printf("\nNombre insertado: %d", encontrar(a, aux2)->nombre);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nNo encontrado");
        }
        break;


    }...
```

**Código en el header:**

```
#

ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo_arbol
{
    int valor;                       /* Campo donde almacenaremos el valor */
    char nombre[255];
    struct nodo_arbol *izq;    /* Puntero al hijo izquierdo */
    struct nodo_arbol *der;      /* Puntero al hijo derecho */
}NODO_ARBOL, *P_NODO_ARBOL;


P_NODO_ARBOL crearArbol();
int esVacio(P_NODO_ARBOL a);
P_NODO_ARBOL insertar(P_NODO_ARBOL arbol, int i);
P_NODO_ARBOL encontrar (P_NODO_ARBOL arbol, int i);
void preOrder(P_NODO_ARBOL a);
void postOrder(P_NODO_ARBOL a);
void inOrder(P_NODO_ARBOL a);


#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

**Función.h:**

```
P_NODO_ARBOL insertar(P_NODO_ARBOL arbol, int i)

{
    int x;
    P_NODO_ARBOL p;    /* Para no perder la cabeza del arbol */
    //P_NODO_ARBOL h;    /* Para no perder la cabeza del arbol */

    if (arbol == NULL)
    {
        p = alojar_nodo_arbol();             
        p->izq = p->der = NULL;             
        p->valor = i;

        return (p);
    }

    if (arbol->valor == i)    

        return (arbol);

    if (arbol->valor > i) /* "i" es menor que el valor que analizo, por tanto,
                           inserto a la izquierda */
        arbol->izq = insertar(arbol->izq, i);


    else  
        arbol->der = insertar(arbol->der, i);


    return (arbol);
}
```

Comment: Nos dices qué quieres, pero no cuál es el problema (¿el código falla? ¿cómo falla? ¿sabes dónde está el error?). Intenta acotar un poco la "pregunta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te  recomiendo lo siguiente. Vos queres almacenar un nombre y un telefono bajo un mismo nombre de variable, esto se soluciona facilmente declarando una estructura cuyos campos sean el nombre y el telefono. 
Si aplicas esto solamente insertarias nodos de este tipo de estructura.
PD: te recomiendo manipular los telefonos como cadenas de caracteres

```
typedef struct {
 char nombre[255];
 char telefono[16];
}datos;

typedef  struct nodo_arbol{
    datos info;
    struct nodo_arbol *izq;   
    struct nodo_arbol *der;    
}NODO_ARBOL, *P_NODO_ARBOL;
```

Luego al insertar vos decidis por que campo ordenar, di por telefono o por nombre. La comparación de si la cadena actual es menor a mayor a la que se va a insertar lo podes averiguar con strcmp o alguna variante.

La forma de acceder a cada campo seria 
NODO_ARBOL p;
p->info.nombre;

Espero que te sirva, cualquier consulta decime.